# Can I get enum like functionality for strings in .net?

Tags: .net, string, list, enums

I'm trying to come up with a way to keep a list of strings to be used within my project.

So lets say I have a list of websites:

```
www.website1.com
www.website2.com
www.website3.com
www.website4.com
```

I was hoping I could get something working similar to how enums work with ints.

When someone needs to check the url they will have a list they can choose from and would be able to write something like this maybe

```
WebsiteNames.Website1
```

Is there a good(clean) way to do this?

Comment: If 'someone'='user' then just use an array?  Also, these kinds of things should not be hardcoded, be sure to use a config file or database.

Comment: I might go ahead with what Wouter de Kort suggested: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a static class like this:

```
public static class WebSiteNames
{
   public readonly string Website1 = "www.website1.com";
   public readonly string Website2 = "www.website2.com";
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
WebSiteNames.Website1
```

If you have a look at [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) you could even generate a file like this automatically so you won't have to worrie about writing it by hand or runtime errors if someone changes something in the code.

Answer (score 2):

A class like so should do it:

```
public static class WebSiteNames
{
  public static readonly string Website1 = "www.website1.com";
  public static readonly string Website2 = "www.website2.com";
}
```

If a field is publicly exposed it's generally best to make it static readonly rather than const, since any change in the value of the string would require all dependent modules to be re-compiled to get the change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `struct` like this:

```
public struct WebSiteNames
{
    public const string Website1 = "www.website1.com";
    public const string Website2 = "www.website2.com";
    public const string Website3 = "www.website3.com";
    public const string Website4 = "www.website4.com";
}
```

Since `struct` is a `value type`, its usage is similar to `enums`.

Comment: What's the benefit of using a struct here? A static class is a much better choice; you don't need the value type semantics here, so using a struct is just confusing...

Comment: Also, using a struct prevents you from making it static, and you can't make the default constructor private. So it is possible to create an instance of this type, which doesn't make sense at all